# Does a consistent theory of retributive punishment require belief in freewill?

Tags: ethics, free-will

Is it "possible" to accept a retributive theory of punishment, while simultaneously accepting a deterministic view of human behavior? Is belief in freewill a necessary condition for a belief that retributive punishments are ethical/correct? Under what set of assumptions are these ideas compatible?

Comment: You may be interested in [http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/]

Comment: I think there's a lot of different things that are tangled together here, but I think the basic answer is that it is possible to (a) accept determinism (on some definition of determinism) and (b) believe retributive punishment is ethically appropriate  (on some definition of ethics).

Answer (score 0):

No. See Harry Frankfurt's work on moral responsibility and free will.

http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~uctytho/dfwCompatFrankfurt.htm

Comment: Could you summarize his main arguments here, please? Links are susceptible to linkrot, and so on a few years this answer may boil down to nothing more than "no", with no supporting evidence.